# Netbeans refuses to auto suggest known classes for imports

Tags: java, netbeans, import, autosuggest

I just discovered that my NetBeans suddenly stops importing classes that are found in the Java API but can still import classes from my external libraries. Take a look at the image below:

[image: NetBeans editor]

As you can see, `List` and `ArrayList` are classes from the `java.util` package but the usual suggestions for importing them are not shown here, instead it is asking me to create class. I know that I can type `import java.util.List;` on the top of the code but life was better before! Please I need help thanks.

Comment: If you add import manually does netbeans recognize it?

Comment: It will, but like I said life was better when imports where automatic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem a couple minutes ago... Terrible. The same problem has been reported here:

[Bug 235712](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=235712)

The solution which I've found there was sufficient - simply delete the Netbeans cache...

In order to do this, go to Help ==> About . Then go to the directory with cache and delete all you find in the  "index" catalog.

[image]

After restarting the NB, everything was cool.

Answer (score 6):

Today I came across the same problem. It happens that it actually is very easy to exclude a class from code completion if you click in the wrong place while working.

To solve it (netbeans 8.2) go to

Tools - Options -> Editor tab

Then select Code Completion Tab

In the drop Down select JAVA (in my case it was Java)

You will find a box bellow titled Package/Classes
In the EXCLUDE tab you probably will find the packages marked to be excluded from code completion. Just remove the ones you want back.

Answer (score 0):

Check under `Preferences->Editor->Code Completion` to make sure auto complete is on, though by your screen shot I assume that it is.

Also try `Preferences->Editor->Formatting` and set your Language to `Java`

Comment: if you do `ctrl+O` in netbeans and type `List` for example do you see the suggestions?

Comment: I did ctrl+O and typed List, but I did not see any suggestions. I also typed my own classes and I saw them! What could be the problem?

Comment: did you set the language to java?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, NetBeans was refusing to suggest `Scanner`. As it turned out, all I had to do was remove `java.util.Scanner` from Options » Editor » Code Completion » Packages/classes: » Exclude. Then the autocompletion for `Scanner` returned.

[image]